# How to save Highscore after app closed?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I want to save the highscore, even after App is closed, on how many times I clicked the Imagebutton. I want to see the highscore the whole time the app is running
But when I try my code the App crashed every time and I dont know where I made a mistake.

EDIT: Now the App doesn't crach but the Highscore ist always Zero!
EDIT 2: Got it now! This is the code that works for me.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView cirlce;
private TextView Zahl;
private ImageButton reset;
int counter = 0;
int readHighscore;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cirlce = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Zahl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Zahl);
    Zahl.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    TextView highscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
    highscore.setText(Integer.toString(readHighscore));

 cirlce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            Zahl.setText(Integer.toString(counter));



   cirlce.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            Zahl.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            TextView highscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
            highscore.setText(Integer.toString(readHighscore));

            if (readHighscore > counter) {
                highscore.setText(Integer.toString(readHighscore));

            }
            else {
                readHighscore = counter;
                highscore.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

            }
```

SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        readHighscore = prefs.getInt("highscore", 0);

```
    if (readHighscore > counter) {
        highscore.setText(Integer.toString(readHighscore));

    }
    else {
        readHighscore = counter;
        highscore.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("highscore", readHighscore);

    editor.commit();

}
```

}

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/x"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cirlce"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="82dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Zahl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@null"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/highscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/Highscore" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any errors in Logcat?

Comment: @Jessef.       Add your crash (Log) report.

Comment: EDIT: Now the App doesn't crach but the Highscore ist always Zero!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a key for your highscore value

> editor.putInt("", readHighscore);

Change To

> editor.putInt("Score", readHighscore);